# What does "Use BalanceTags" Do?

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite installation, and I was changing the settings of one of my sites from the mu administration panel when I came across a setting called `Use BalanceTags`. Out of curiosity, what does that setting do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

balanceTags fixes incorrectly nested html markup, for instance if you had an opening tag but no closing tag, or if they're closed in the wrong order.